# UIWebView localization as per phone settings

Tags: ios, uiwebview, localization

`Safari` changes the content of web page based on selected phone language. How to do this for a `UIWebView` ? Just to tell, I have set `CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations` as **Yes** in **Info.plist**.

Comment: Is this for iOS 10?  I've noticed a change where the UIWebView is showing wrong character variations for Japanese.  Testing between Chinese and Japanese, it seems to be showing the opposite (wrong) variation when setting a font-family (to say Helvetica).  If I leave font-family out, it looks OK.  If I swap the priority order of Japanese and Chinese in settings, things swap (backwards from what I expect).  I think there's a bug.  I'm not sure if this is what you are experiencing.